# how to scrape a dynamic website without selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i am facing an issue that i hope anyone can help me with.
i'm trying to scrape a webpage using selenium package on python but it keeps detecting that i'm using selenium and redirects me to a log in page that i can't use.
i tried using a fake agent but it still detected me, i tried changing the "$cdc" in the chrome driver but it still didn't work. apperciate if anyone can help me.
here is the code i'm using :

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument('enable-automation')
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
#options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.mcmaster.com/nuts/hex-nuts/medium-strength-steel-hex-nuts-grade-5/")
```